# How to get arrowheads on vertical and horizontal lines with MeshFunctions in ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting, mesh

I want to get such plot, using `MeshFunctions`

[image]

```
data = {{12, 2}, {5, 2}, {5, 4}, {14, 4}, {14, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 5}, {18, 5}, {18, 0}};
ListLinePlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, "Medium"}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, Mesh -> 2, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0], 
MeshShading -> {Arrowheads[Medium]}] /. Line -> Arrow
```

gives arrowheads on horizontal lines:

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, "Medium"},  MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> 2, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0], 
  MeshShading -> {Arrowheads[Medium]}] /. Line -> Arrow
```

gives arrowheads on vertical lines:

[image]

But how to get arrowheads on both lines? Of course, I can combine two plots with `Show`. But is it possible to get one plot with arrowheads on vertical and horizontal lines?  `MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}` didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of replacing a `Line` – which can go through multiple points – with a single `Arrow`, replace it with a sequence of multiple consecutive two-points arrows. Then you can tune the spacings with `Mesh`.

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, "Medium"}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, Mesh -> {2, 2}, 
  MeshStyle -> Opacity[0], 
  MeshShading -> {{arrowheads}, {arrowheads}}] /. 
 Line[pts_] :> (Arrow /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1])
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 3):

To change every line into an arrow:

```
data = {{12, 2}, {5, 2}, {5, 4}, {14, 4}, {14, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 
    5}, {18, 5}, {18, 0}};
ListLinePlot[data] /. Line[x__] :> Arrow[Partition[x, 2, 1]]
```

[image]

Or if you want several arrows on each line:

```
ListLinePlot[data] /. 
 Line[x__] :> {Arrow[Partition[x, 2, 1]], 
   Arrow[Partition[Riffle[#, Mean /@ Partition[#, 2, 1]] &[data], 2]]}
```

[image]